# LOD from Tableau to Power BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I move the dashboard from Tableau to Power BI.

I need to replace LOD expression from Tableau in Power BI.

{FIXED [Training Name]: MAX(Training hours)*MAX(Training sessions)}

Business logic:

I want to calculate sum for every training (traing hours*training sessions)

Dummy data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGSW.png)

Any help? :)

Comment: Welcome to stacoverflow. Edit your question and add some dummy data + desired result; Describe business logic for this calculation instead of pasting Tableau code; Users may don't know what this calculation does in Tableau.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.